# How to create a LiveTile on Windows Phone 7 series

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do you create a live tile? Do you have to create a special sort of XAML file or is it predefined and we just pass parameters or both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create an application which can be pinned to the start screen by the user. The image of the tile used is in your application. After that you can use the pushnotification system to update the picture of the tile.

it's not possible to create a tile which animates like the xbox live tile for example.

Comment: can you link to an example of a live tile in a custom application?